# How to set the prediction range of ARIMA model in R

Tags: r, arima, prediction, ggplot2

I am new to R and statistics. I have a problem related to the prediction:
I am not able to plot the real value together with the predicted value. 
PROBLEM: I want to feed first 16 values into the ARIMA and then I want ARIMA should predict the next 3 values. I used both forecast and predict function but not sure which one is good for my case (please tell me).
After prediction, I only can plot the green line which is the prediction values but not able to add the real values in the same line.

Bonus: How to get the MAPE error measure when I use predict function in R.

Thanks..

SAMPLE CODE:

```
x=file$Cost
    k<-auto.arima(x[1:16]) 
    m=forecast(k,h=3) ## I tried both of them
    m=predict(k, n.ahead = 3)
    j=(m$fitted)
a=j[17:19]
b=x[17:19]
plot(a, col="green",type="l") # predicted
lines(b) # real
summary(m)
```

SAMPLE DATA:

```
Timestamp   Cost
2010-09-21T00:00:00+00:00   5
2010-09-21T00:01:00+00:00   6
2010-09-21T00:02:00+00:00   6
2010-09-21T00:03:00+00:00   6
2010-09-21T00:04:00+00:00   6
2010-09-21T00:05:00+00:00   6
2010-09-21T00:06:00+00:00   6
2010-09-21T00:07:00+00:00   5
2010-09-21T00:08:00+00:00   6
2010-09-21T00:09:00+00:00   5
2010-09-21T01:10:00+00:00   5
2010-09-21T01:11:00+00:00   6
2010-09-21T01:12:00+00:00   6 
2010-09-21T01:13:00+00:00   6
2010-09-21T01:14:00+00:00   6
2010-09-21T01:15:00+00:00   6
2010-09-21T01:16:00+00:00   6
2010-09-21T01:17:00+00:00   5
2010-09-21T01:18:00+00:00   6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `forecast` function, and then simply `plot` its output. The help page on `?forecast.Arima` is useful. (It's admittedly not easy to find - note the capital "A"!) You can get error measures using `accuracy`:

```
library(forecast)
model <- auto.arima(AirPassengers[1:120])
fcst <- forecast(model,h=12)
plot(fcst)
accuracy(f=fcst,x=AirPassengers[121:132])
                     ME     RMSE      MAE        MPE     MAPE      MASE        ACF1
Training set  0.1044514 20.96255 16.48924 -0.7528006 6.821832 0.7441104 -0.00437311
Test set     15.9476890 61.62388 44.80443  1.8956474 9.660103 2.0218911          NA
```

[image: forecast]

If you only want to plot the point forecasts and the actuals, you can extract them (using `fcst$mean`), convert them into a `ts` object and plot like this:

```
plot(ts(AirPassengers[121:132],start=c(1959,1),frequency=12),ylab="")
lines(ts(fcst$mean,start=c(1959,1),frequency=12),col="red")
```

[image: forecast again]

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply(MAPE solved but the plot is not :)), but I want to only plot the forecasted 12 value (h=12) together with real 12 value (which I have in the data set but not fed into the model): I did   plot(m); lines(x[RANGE]).

Comment: I edited the answer. Better?